# Combine 2 regex patterns to get a substring

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a text file which I want to parse and "sanitise". Sample data from the file

```
Trade '4379160'\Acquire Day 2015-05-07      Create  acquire_day
Trade '4379160'\Fund    XXXY        Create  acquirer_ptynbr
Trade '4379160'\Assinf          Create  assinf
Trade '4379160'\Authorizer          Create  authorizer_usrnbr
Trade '4379160'\Base Curr Equivalent    0       Create  base_cost_dirty
```

What I want to achieve is to get the first 2 "fields" after the first backslash. For e.g., `Acquire Day 2015-05-07`. Note that sometime the second field is empty (which is OK - I don't need any *Create* string). What I've done is to use `RegEx` to first find anything after backslash and then get the 2 required fields. My test code so far

```
Private Sub SanitiseTradeAudit(fileInput)
    Dim objFSO, objFile, regEx, validTxt, validTxt1, arrValidTxt, i

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileInput, 1) 
    validTxt = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = Nothing

    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = "(.*)\'\\(.*)" 'To Remove all [[ Trade '4379160'\ ]] prefix from audit lines
    regEx.Global = True 
    validTxt = regEx.Replace(validTxt, "$2") 'Text would be ==> Aggregate   0       Create  aggregate

    regEx.Pattern = "[(\t.*)](\t.*)" 'Pick only first 2 data points ==> Aggregate   0
    regEx.Global = True
    validTxt1 = regEx.Replace(validTxt, vbCr)

    arrValidTxt = Split(validTxt1, vbCrLf) 'To Remove the first 2 header lines, split it based on new line
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileInput, 2)
    For i = 2 To (Ubound(arrValidTxt) - 1) 'Ignore first 2 header lines
        objFile.WriteLine arrValidTxt(i)
    Next
    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = Nothing

    Set regEx = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End sub


Call SanitiseTradeAudit("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\ActualAuditMessage.txt")
```

My question is - can this regex replacement be done in one single pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern like this should work if you process the file line by line:

```
^.*?\\([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)
```

The above matches everything up to the first backslash (non-greedy match) followed by two groups of zero or more non-tab characters (greedy match) separated by a single tab.

Sample code:

```vb
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^.*?\\([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)"

txt = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileInput).ReadAll

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileInput)
For Each line In Split(txt, vbNewLine)
  For Each m In re.Execute(line)
    objFile.WriteLine m.SubMatches(0) & vbTab & m.SubMatches(1)
  Next
Next
objFile.Close
```

If you need to process large files I'd drop the `ReadAll` entirely and read the input file line by line to avoid memory exhaustion:

```vb
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^.*?\\([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)"

Set inFile  = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileInput)
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileOutput, 2, True)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  For Each m In re.Execute(line)
    objFile.WriteLine m.SubMatches(0) & vbTab & m.SubMatches(1)
  Next
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

Comment: I don't wanna process the file line by line .. I did it cause I couldn't imagine any other way. Your way is shorter in coding bit, but am not really sure if it would be faster.

Comment: I executed with a sample test data of 51k lines. As suspected, my original code took 0.953125 seconds and your code took 2.121094 seconds. I would be processing much larger file.

Comment: @PankajJaju Then I would specifically recommend processing the file line by line (although in a slightly different way) in order to avoid the risk of memory exhaustion. See updated answer.

Comment: I adapted your code and it worked out in the end effectively.